# Where and when to use Lambda?

Tags: ruby, language-agnostic, lambda

I am trying to understand why do we really need lambda or proc in ruby (or any other language for that matter)?

```
#method
def add a,b
  c = a+b
end

#using proc
def add_proc a,b
  f = Proc.new {|x,y| x + y }
  f.call a,b
end

#using lambda function
def add_lambda a,b
  f = lambda {|x,y| x + y}
  f.call a,b
end

puts add 1,1
puts add_proc 1,2
puts add_lambda 1,3
```

I can do a simple addition using: 1. normal function def, 2. using proc and 3. using lambda.

But why and where use lambda in the real world? Any examples where functions cannot be used and lambda should be used.

Comment: I too would like to know why we need a lambda in a programming language, any function would serve the purpose equally.

Comment: [Language agnostic question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150129/what-is-a-lambda?lq=1)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's true, you don't *need* anonymous functions (or lambdas, or whatever you want to call them).  But there are a lot of things you don't *need*.  You don't need classes—just pass all the instance variables around to ordinary functions.  Then

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :bar, :baz
  def frob(x)
    bar = baz*x
  end
end
```

would become

```
def new_Foo(bar,baz)
  [bar,baz]
end

def bar(foo)
  foo[0]
end
# Other attribute accessors stripped for brevity's sake

def frob(foo,x)
  foo[0] = foo[1]*x
end
```

Similarly, you don't *need* any loops except for `loop...end` with `if` and `break`.  I could go on and on.<sup>1</sup>  But you *want* to program with classes in Ruby.  You *want* to be able to use `while` loops, or maybe even `array.each { |x| ... }`, and you want to be able to use `unless` instead of `if not`.

Just like these features, anonymous functions are there to help you express things elegantly, concisely, and sensibly.  Being able to write `some_function(lambda { |x,y| x + f(y) })` is much nicer than having to write

```
def temp(x,y)
  x + f(y)
end
some_function temp
```

It's much bulkier to have to break off the flow of code to write out a `def`fed function, which then has to be given a useless name, when it's just as clear to write the operation in-line.  It's true that there's nowhere you *must* use a lambda, but there are lots of places I'd much *rather* use a lambda.

Ruby solves a lot of the lambda-using cases with blocks: all the functions like `each`, `map`, and `open` which can take a block as an argument are basically taking a special-cased anonymous function.  `array.map { |x| f(x) + g(x) }` is the same as `array.map(&lambda { |x| f(x) + g(x) })` (where the `&` just makes the lambda "special" in the same way that the bare block is).  Again, you *could* write out a separate `def`fed function every time—but why would you *want* to?

Languages other than Ruby which support that style of programming don't have blocks, but often support a lighter-weight lambda syntax, such as Haskell's `\x -> f x + g x`, or C#'s `x => f(x) + g(x);`<sup>2</sup>.  Any time I have a function which needs to take some abstract behavior, such as `map`, or `each`, or `on_clicked`, I'm going to be thankful for the ability to pass in a lambda instead of a named function, because it's just that much *easier*.  Eventually, you stop thinking of them as somehow special—they're about as exciting as literal syntax for arrays instead of `empty().append(1).append(2).append(3)`.  Just another useful part of the language.

---

**1:** In the degenerate case, you really only need [eight instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck): `+-<>[].,`.  `<>` move an imaginary "pointer" along an array; `+-` increment and decrement the integer in the current cell; `[]` perform a loop-while-non-zero; and `.,` do input and output.  In fact, you really only need just [one instruction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_instruction_set_computer), such as `subleq a b c` (subtract `a` from `b` and jump to `c` if the result is less than or equal to zero).

**2:** I've never actually used C#, so if that syntax is wrong, feel free to correct it.

Comment: You have only one instruction in your second example, but more than one symbol. Life can be simpler.(http://esolangs.org/wiki/Iota) Of course, then (I think) you end up using lambda functions a lot...

Answer (score 7):

#### Blocks are more-or-less the same thing

Well, in Ruby, one doesn't usually use lambda or proc, because blocks are about the same thing and much more convenient.

The uses are infinite, but we can list some typical cases. One normally thinks of functions as lower-level blocks performing a piece of the processing, perhaps written generally and made into a library.

But quite often one wants to automate the wrapper and provide a custom library. Imagine a function that makes an HTTP or HTTPS connection, or a straight TCP one, feeds the I/O to its client, and then closes the connection.  Or perhaps just does the same thing with a plain old file.

So in Ruby we would put the function in a library and have it take a block for the user .. the client .. the "caller"  to write his application logic.

In another language this would have to be done with a class that implements an interface, or a function pointer. Ruby has blocks, but they are all examples of a lambda-style design pattern.

Answer (score 7):

1) It is just a convenience. You don't need to name certain blocks

```
special_sort(array, :compare_proc => lambda { |left, right| left.special_param <=> right.special_param }
```

*(imagine if you had to name all these blocks)*

2) #lambda is usually used to create clojures:

```
def generate_multiple_proc(cofactor)
  lambda { |element| element * cofactor }
end

[1, 2, 3, 4].map(&generate_multiple_proc(2)) # => [2, 3, 5, 8]

[1, 2, 3, 4].map(&generate_multiple_proc(3)) # => [3, 6, 9, 12]
```

Answer (score 6):

It comes down to style. Lambdas are a a declarative style, methods are an imperative style. Consider this:

Lambda, blocks, procs, are all different types of closure. Now the question is, when and why to use an anonymous closure. I can answer that - at least in ruby!

Closures contain the lexical context of where they were called from. If you call a method from within a method, you do not get the context of where the method was called. This is due to the way the object chain is stored in the AST.

A Closure (lambda) on the other hand, can be passed WITH lexical context through a method, allowing for lazy evaluation.

Also lambdas naturally lend themselves to recursion and enumeration.

Answer (score 2):

I found this helpful in understanding the differences:

http://www.robertsosinski.com/2008/12/21/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-lambdas/

But in general the point is sometimes your writing a method but you don't know what you're going to want to do at a certain point in that method, so you let the caller decide.

E.g.:

```
def iterate_over_two_arrays(arr1, arr2, the_proc)
  arr1.each do |x|
    arr2.each do |y|
      # ok I'm iterating over two arrays, but I could do lots of useful things now
      #  so I'll leave it up to the caller to decide by passing in a proc
      the_proc.call(x,y)
    end
  end
end
```

Then instead of writing a `iterate_over_two_arrays_and_print_sum` method and a `iterate_over_two_arrays_and_print_product` method you just call:

```
iterate_over_two_arrays([1,2,3], [4,5,6], Proc.new {|x,y| puts x + y }
```

or

```
iterate_over_two_arrays([1,2,3], [4,5,6], Proc.new {|x,y| puts x * y }
```

so it's more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

In case of OOP, you should create a function in a class only if there should be such an operation on the class according to your domain modeling.

If you need a quick function which can be written inline such as for comparison etc, use a lambda

Also check these SO posts -

[When to use lambda, when to use Proc.new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626/when-to-use-lambda-when-to-use-proc-new)

[C# Lambda expressions: Why should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167343/c-lambda-expression-why-should-i-use-this)

[When to use a lambda in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232817/when-to-use-a-lambda-in-rails)

Answer (score 2):

They're used as "higher-order" functions. Basically, for cases where you pass one function to another, so that the receiving function can call the passed-in one according to its own logic.

This is common in Ruby for iteration, e.g. some_list.each { |item| ... } to do something to `each` `item` of `some_list`. Although notice here that we don't use the keyword `lambda`; as noted, a block is basically the same thing.

In Python (since we have a `language-agnostic` tag on this question) you can't write anything quite like a Ruby block, so the `lambda` keyword comes up more often. However, you can get a similar "shortcut" effect from list comprehensions and generator expressions.