# Ruby: Proc.new { 'waffles' } vs. proc { 'waffles' }

Tags: ruby, syntax, proc-object

In Ruby, are there any differences between `Proc.new { 'waffles' }` and `proc { 'waffles' }`? I have found very few mentions of the second syntax.

From testing using `irb`, I haven't found any obvious differences. Is the second syntactic sugar for the first?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

From Metaprogamming Ruby Page 113.

In Ruby 1.8, Kernel#proc() is actually a synonym for Kernel#lambda(). Because of loud protest from programmers, Ruby 1.9 made proc() a synonym for Proc.new() instead.

Comment: Glorious. I'm using 1.9, so in my case, there are no differences.

Comment: See also: http://books.google.ca/books?id=jcUbTcr5XWwC&pg=PA194&lpg=PA194&dq=ruby+proc+synonym&source=bl&ots=fHJltd8taE&sig=pHkE5W-c9iHHHHfacmuPzeYuI48&hl=en&ei=fuMzTanHDo2usAPyqLTgBQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CDUQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=ruby%20proc%20synonym&f=false