# rails 4 rubocop use proc instead of Proc.new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-style-guide

[image]

```
  validates_presence_of :job, if: Proc.new { |data| data.executed_at? }
```

I have been tinkering with fixing this issue and it continually fails.  If I switch to the recommended proc it chokes on:

[image]

What is the best way to process this and pass the cops?

In case others land here, the final syntax was:

```
validates_presence_of :job, if: proc { executed_at? }
```

Comment: Well, the error message says: "Use `proc` instead of `Proc.new`" ... I'm not sure how to expand on that? Did you try this?

Comment: yes, hence the second step posted.. it chokes on the next step

Comment: What second step? It still shows an error on `Proc.new` in the second image. In fact, both errors are 100% identical.

Comment: The second error changes "Proc" to "proc"

Comment: Not in the errors you posted.

Comment: Also, don't post screenshots. Post text.

Comment: that was my mistake @Carpetsmoker, sorry about that, I just updated it

Comment: You are still using `proc.new` Not `proc` as the error says. `proc.new != proc`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, are you referring to just use proc &:executed_at? thank you for your help walking through this

Comment: also, if you could post an answer @Carpetsmoker I want to make sure to give you credit

Comment: Yeah, `proc` is a keyword. You can just use `proc { my_code }`. See: [Ruby: Proc.new { 'waffles' } vs. proc { 'waffles' }](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710538/ruby-proc-new-waffles-vs-proc-waffles). It's the same as `Proc.new`.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker can you create an answer, your help worked "validates_presence_of :job, if: proc { executed_at? }"

Comment: thank you for your help @Carpetsmoker

Answer (score 1):

You've simply fixed one issue to be confronted with another. Time to fix that one.

```
validates_presence_of :job, if: :executed_at?
```

Comment: in trying that I get the error "ArgumentError: tried to create Proc object without a block"

Comment: Right. On the flip side, I think we can just pass the method name as a symbol. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation I've updated my answer.

Comment: with @Carpetsmoker's help it works with validates_presence_of :job, if: proc { executed_at? } but I am waiting the posted answer so I can give credit.  if you want it first go for it, you both were helping me

Comment: I think that's more than than you need. You don't really need a proc in this case. I suspect either `if: Proc.new(&:executed_at?)` or `proc(&:executed_at?)` would work, too, but I'm not sure.

Comment: the comment he posted fixed the issue, and I updated it so others do not post on this topic.  thank you again for the help